# install_failed_no_matching_abis failed to extract native libraries res=-113 after updating to android 8.0 oreo

Tags: android

I have an issue with my app. I use a samsung s8 and my app was running fine until I updated to android oreo. I uninstalled my app and tried to run again but I get error install_failed_no_matching_abis failed to extract native libraries res=-113 . My app still runs ok on other devices. I read these posts :
[Error INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS after updating Nexus 5x to Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287292/error-install-failed-no-matching-abis-after-updating-nexus-5x-to-oreo/49749110#49749110)
[INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS error on Android 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094281/install-failed-no-matching-abis-error-on-android-8?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
[[INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414219/install-failed-no-matching-abis-failed-to-extract-native-libraries-res-113)

but nothing seems to work for me. I cannot figure out if I have to remove some libraries, the ones that are mentioned do not exist in my app, or if I have to add something.  I also tried to add

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

in my gradle but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 32 bit libraries, try to use

```
android {
    defaultConfig {

        ...

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
```

Note that inclusion of 64 bit libraries ("arm64-v8a") will be mandatory since the August 2019.