# Installation apk in android 8.0 error

Tags: android, installation

I have benn trying for many days to install an app on any device using android oreo either in debug mode with android studio either by creating apk,  but I still fail. At the beggining I had issue described here [install_failed_no_matching_abis failed to extract native libraries res=-113 after updating to android 8.0 oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749330/install-failed-no-matching-abis-failed-to-extract-native-libraries-res-113-afte/49749898#49749898)
and while I am trying to solve this I get different errors all the time. 
When I set `android.enableAapt2=true` I get this error 
[image]

when I set `android.enableAapt2=false` I get warning

```
 The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
I`t will be removed at the end of 2018..`
```

and finally this error comes up
[image]

and this in log Mesagges

```
04-17 01:37:27.331 9763-11258/? E/xiy: Job(ItemMessageAttachmentsCacheEvictorJob#0.126) Enqueued job 'ItemMessageAttachmentsCacheEvictorJob' failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attachment cache cannot be null.
    at piu.a(Unknown Source:4)
    at pki.a(Unknown Source:17)
    at yik.a(SourceFile:1)
    at xik.b(SourceFile:2)
    at xil.a(Unknown Source:4)
    at yik.a(SourceFile:1)
    at yhr.run(SourceFile:1)
    at wzc.run(Unknown Source:3)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:782)
```

Either way I cannot install my app on any device running oreo although it works fine up to nougat.Even if I buld apk ig get error parsing apk file.

Comment: Aapt2 error maybe case by .9 resources ,check .9 resources

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: Yes I did according to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094281/install-failed-no-matching-abis-error-on-android-8?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa